# How to print an array which is divisible by two numbers?

Tags: javascript

I found myself a problem. I want to print an array from number 0 to 100.
if the number is divisible by 3, I want to print flip.
if the number is divisible by 5, I want to print flop.
for example the array should be [0,1,2,'flip',4,'flop','flip,........,'flop'].
How to do this in JS?
So far I have done this but it doesn't print the whole array.

```
function wow() {
  var arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if(i!=0){
      if(i%3===0){
        i='flip'
        arr.push(i)
      }
      if(i%5===0){
        i='flop'
        arr.push(i)
      }
    }
    arr.push(i)
  }
  console.log(arr)
}
wow()
```

Comment: You are messing up the `i`. Use a different variable or just use the string directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the variable i within the for loop which you shouldn't be doing. Try using a temp variable for determining what gets pushed to your array.

Also, if a number is divisible by 3 AND 5 then the latter (flop) takes precedent, is that what you expect to happen?

```js
function wow() {
  var arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    let temp = i;
    if (i != 0) {


      if (i % 3 === 0) {
        temp = 'flip'
      }
      if (i % 5 === 0) {
        temp = 'flop'
      }
    }
    arr.push(temp)

  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit shorter version...

```js
let arr = Array.from({
  length: 101
}, (e, i) => i)

arr.forEach((n, i) => {
  Number.isInteger(n / 3) ? arr[i] = 'flip' : null, Number.isInteger(n / 5) ? arr[i] = 'flop' : null
})


console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dot = (a,b) => x => a(b(x));
const id = x => x;


function flipflop(n){
  const f = (N, m) => n % N ? id : x => _ => m + x('');
  return dot(f(3, 'flip'), f(5, 'flop')) (id) (n);
}

let arr = Array(101).fill(0).map((_,i)=>flipflop(i));
console.log(arr);
```